# Existe a possibilidade de criar um handleChange para uma form que pega os valores de um store Redux?

Tags: formulário, react, mongoose, redux

Seguinte, estou criando um app e me deparei com este problema: Tenho uma store setada e quero criar um form de atualização dos dados no Atlas(MongoDB). Porém quero que esse form, já venha com os valores que estão na store. Até ai tudo bem... Agora minha dúvida é: **Como criar um handleChange** pra essa situação?Já que somente acessar os dados nesse caso não basta...

**OBS: Os dados são algo como:

```js
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {date: {…}, _id: "5d66d1ffaafb603850a450be", value: 359, category: "Mercado", author: "5d66bb426d80e62f54d02724", …}

1: {date: {…}, _id: "5d66d5f9aad2665674d2be1f", value: 359, category: "Cartão", author: "5d66bb426d80e62f54d02724", …}

2: {date: {…}, _id: "5d6aafa4b89a1d11a08f1890", value: 4500, category: "Salário", author: "5d66bb426d80e62f54d02724", …}

3: {date: {…}, _id: "5d6ab44bb89a1d11a08f1893", value: 112, category: "Salário", author: "5d66bb426d80e62f54d02724", …}

4: {date: {…}, _id: "5d6ab458b89a1d11a08f1894", value: 1000, category: "Salário", author: "5d66bb426d80e62f54d02724", …}

length: 5__proto__: Array(0)
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Actions from '../../redux/actions'
// import useForm from '../../useHooks/useForm'

const Crud = ({title}) => {

    const wallet = useSelector(state => state.wallet)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    let data = []

    let patch = ''
    let deleteItem = ''

    if(title === "Entradas") {
        data = wallet.entrys.all
        patch = (id) => {
            dispatch(Actions.entryUpdReq(id))
        }
        deleteItem = (id) => {
            dispatch(Actions.delEntryReq(id))
        }
    } else if(title === "Despesas") {
        data = wallet.outs.all
        patch = (id) => {
            dispatch(Actions.outUpdReq(id))
        }

        deleteItem = (id) => {
            dispatch(Actions.delOutReq(id))
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="crud">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th valign="center">Valor</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th>Opções</th>
                </tr>
                {!wallet.loading && wallet.entrys.all && wallet.outs.all && data.length >=1 ?
                <>
                    {data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td><input  value={item.value} /></td>
                                <td><input value={item.category} /></td>
                                <td>{`${item.date.day} de ${item.date.month}`}</td>
                                <td className="btn-opts">
                                    <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item._id)}>Deletar</button>
                                    <button onClick={() => patch(item._id)}>Salvar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </> :
                <p>Carregando...</p>
                }
            </table>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Crud
```

Comment: Fala Gabe, beleza? Deixa eu tentar entender melhor: Você quer fazer um onChange pra alterar o valor que já está no store do redux? Pelo que ví no seu código, você pega os dados, coloca no input e deixaria o usuário alterar os dados, confere?

Comment: Isso ai, eu consegui resolver na verdade... Muito tosco, sabe quando você ta sem paciencia e não consegue pensar em nada? Foi esse  o momento, fiquei uns minutos vendo alguns vídeos nada a ver no youtube e consegui, criei um state com o valor do store, assim eu posso alterar ele só no componente sem interferir em nada... Mas ai Carlos, muito obrigado! <3

Comment: Tranquilo Gabe. Acredito que essa abordagem aí é melhor e consome menos recurso. Sucesso pra ti.